# BASH - como mezclo expansión de parámetros/variables

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

Alguien de acá sabrá si se pueden mezclar expansión de Parámetros o Variables en Bash?.

Necesito obtener un string y a la vez convertirlo en Uppercase.
 
Exemplo:

```
AMB="un-ejemplo-cualquiera" 
echo "${AMB#*-}" 
echo "${AMB^^}"
```

Entonces, en vez de hacerlo en dos pasos, se podrá en uno solo?. Como para que una variable contengo el string "EJEMPLO-CUALQUIERA" (en Uppercase).

Comment: No son necesario los dos pasos, con usar directamente `"${AMB^^}"` ya lo tienes.

Comment: aaah! perdon, dice String. En realidad necesito obtener el SubString "EJEMPLO-CUALQUIERA" en Uppercase del string "un-ejemplo-cualquiera" . Gracias igual. (espero se entienda esta vez)

Answer (score 0):

Ya!. Menos complicaciones y más rápido. Lo solucione de esta forma, con pipe (por si a alguien le sirve).

```
echo "${AMB#*-}" |tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

*(Igual son dos pasos  :(   )*

Comment: Ya puestos podrias haberlo hecho asi tambien: `AMB="${AMB#*-}" && echo "${AMB^^}"` (tambien es una línea! pero siguen siendo dos pasos)

Comment: mejor dos pasos, ¿no? Es la gracia del mundo UNIX